In SAFe, what is the meaning of AV in the PI Objectives?
In the https://scaledagileframework.com/pi-objectives/ page, when capturing the PI Objectives, you have a BV and AV column.

The BV is Business Value, and is explained. But I don't see a meaning behind AV.
What is this column? What does it contain? When is it updated? Is it achieved value? Actual value? If yes, how is that eventually determined?
Maybe I missed the section of the documentation that explains this, but would need some help to understand what this does.

AV stands for Actual Business Value. This is feedback given (hopefully) in the System Demo by the business stakeholder who gave the estimated Business Value during PI Planning.

It seems a shortcoming of the PI Objectives page that it shows this Objectives but doesn't link to Inspect & Adapt where BV gets filled in.
